# Using Java to decode JSON array of objects

Tags: java, android, json, json-simple

I have JSON as follows:

```
[{"0":"1","id":"1","1":"abc","name":"abc"},{"0":"2","id":"2","1":"xyz","name":"xyz"}]
```

It is an array of objects.

I need to parse it using Java. I am using the library at :
http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/downloads/list

Example 1 at this link approximates what I require:
http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples

I have the following code:

```
/** Decode JSON */
// Assuming the JSON string is stored in jsonResult (String)

Object obj = JSONValue.parse(jsonResult);
JSONArray array = (JSONArray)obj;
JSONObject jsonObj = null;
for (int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
    try {
        jsonObj = (JSONObject) array.get(i);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    try {
        Log.d(TAG,"Object no." + (i+1) + " field1: " + jsonObj.get("0") + " field2:       " + jsonObj.get("1"));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONArray
// at JSONArray array = (JSONArray)obj;
```

Can someone please help?

Thanks.

Comment: You get that error on what line???

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of casting your Object to JSONArray, you should do it like this:

```
JSONArray mJsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
JSONObject mJsonObject = new JSONObject();
for (int i = 0; i < mJsonArray.length(); i++) {
    mJsonObject = mJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    mJsonObject.getString("0");
    mJsonObject.getString("id");
    mJsonObject.getString("1");
    mJsonObject.getString("name");
}
```

Comment: I am surprised this answer worked for you because there is no JSONArray constructor that takes a string!

Comment: @GeekStocks [here it is](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#JSONArray(java.lang.String))

Comment: @Lalit - that's a different class, I am using org.json.simple.JSONArray and the link you gave is org.json.JSONArray so that is the difference...

Comment: @GeekStocks ok but I gave answer considering `org.json.JSONArray`!

Comment: @Lalit - yes that is the difference. There are actually several other packages containing JSONArray classes and this is leading to confusion.