# How to extract specific text from string using Regex in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string

I have a String =  `'["Id","Lender","Type","Aging","Override"]'`

from which I want to extract Id, Lender, Type and so on in an String array. I am trying to extract it using Regex but, the pattern is not removing the "[".

Can someone please guide me. Thanks!

Update: code I tried,

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"(.+?)\"");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while (matcher.find()) {
// System.out.println(matcher.group(1));.
list.add(matcher.group(1));
```

(Ps: new to Regex)

Comment: Please add your tried code

Comment: That looks like a JSON Array, so a JSON parser would be a good choice.

Comment: @Sanjeev added! Thanks.

Comment: I ran your code and it is doing what you want

Comment: Using a JSON Parser is the right way to solve this, You can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264725/using-java-to-decode-json-array-of-objects/8264751#8264751

Comment: @Sanjeev my bad, I just checked it's is working. Your solution also works perfectly. Although, I am still not getting how it is working?
 Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this. It first removes `"[ ]"` and then splits on `","`

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(string.replaceAll("\\[(.*)\\]", "$1").split(",")));
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

but if your input was, say:

```
["Id","Lender","Ty\"pe","Aging","Override", "Override\\\\\"\""]
```

this regex will capture all values, while allowing those (valid) escaped quotes `\"` and literal backslashes `\\` in your strings

- regex: `"((?:\\\\|\\"|[^"])+)"`
- or as java string: `"\"((?:\\\\\\\\|\\\\\"|[^\"])+)\""`

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vT4dC7/2)

Comment: It was helpful! Tnx!

Comment: no prob. you can go here to convert from a regex to properly escaped java string: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, I tried it and I got the output you want.

```
String line = "[\"Id\",\"Lender\",\"Type\",\"Aging\",\"Override\"]";

Pattern r = Pattern.compile("\"(.+?)\"");
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();        
// Now create matcher object.
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
while (m.find( )) {
      result.add(m.group(1));
 } 
System.out.println(result);
```

output:

```
[Id, Lender, Type, Aging, Override]
```

obviously the square brackets are there because I am printing a `List`, they are not part of the words.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected a small error in my code. Now it's working.